# How to access multiple value json elements in yii framework

Tags: json, yii

i am working in extjs+yii. my server side design is in yii framework and client side design is in extjs. Now from extjs i am getting output data in json format as=

```
{"data":[{"optionId":"","questionId":"1","isAnswer":"","option":"Aus","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"2","isAnswer":"","option":"india","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"3","isAnswer":"","option":"England","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"4","isAnswer":"","option":"Srilanka","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null}]}
```

So in Yii frameowk how to access this json fields? i want to access questionId and optionId fields of this json. So can someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

You have to decode the json using [`CJSON::decode`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON#decode-detail), and then access the fields:

```
$var='{"data":[{"optionId":"","questionId":"1","isAnswer":"","option":"Aus","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"2","isAnswer":"","option":"india","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"3","isAnswer":"","option":"England","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"4","isAnswer":"","option":"Srilanka","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null}]}';
$decoded=CJSON::decode($var);
// now your json is stored in $decoded as an array, so you can access as follows:
echo $decoded["data"][0]["questionId"];
echo $decoded["data"][0]["optionId"];
// to loop over the elements use foreach
foreach ($decoded["data"] as $value){
    echo $value["questionId"];
    echo $value["optionId"];
}
```

---

Using `CJSON::decode` is better than relying on native `json_decode`, as when the native is not available CJSON::decode can still decode a json string. [Also in some cases `json_decode` can return `null` for correct json strings](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/web/helpers/CJSON.php#L329), read [here](http://gggeek.altervista.org/sw/article_20070425.html) for a comparison of php json libraries.

Comment: Got solution as-                                                                            
   $obj=json_decode($json);
   foreach( $obj->data as $data)
   {
      echo $data->questionId;
      echo $data->option;
   }

Comment: ok, CJSON decode also works when json_decode is not available in your php, so it's generally better to use CJSON decode (I think it also handles ActiveRecord objects better).

Comment: I have the same format of `json` now I want to save it into my database but I am unable to do it. I have also put a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176679/yii2-how-to-save-received-json-data-into-database)