# Yii2 how to save received JSON data into database

Tags: php, arrays, json, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have created an `API` which returns me an array of data in `json`

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [MSN] => 002999001207 [PingDateTime] => 2018-05-04T16:33:27 [PingValue] => 22 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [MSN] => 002999001195 [PingDateTime] => 2018-05-04T16:34:11 [PingValue] => 21 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [MSN] => 002999001180 [PingDateTime] => 2018-05-04T14:42:40 [PingValue] => 20 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [MSN] => 002999001157 [PingDateTime] => 2018-05-04T14:42:52 [PingValue] => 30 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [MSN] => 002999001142 [PingDateTime] => 2018-05-04T16:37:19 [PingValue] => 13 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [MSN] => 002999001138 [PingDateTime] => 2018-05-04T16:32:22 [PingValue] => 20 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [MSN] => 002999001114 [PingDateTime] => 2018-05-04T16:32:52 [PingValue] => 22 )
```

Now, I am trying to save it in my `DB`

```
    $curl = curl_init($api_url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Key'));

    $m->start_date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($curl_response);
    $record = $json->data;

    foreach ($record as $item){
        if($this->isSaved($item->MSN))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if($this->ogpCreated($item->MSN))
        {
           $m->end_date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
           $m->meter_msn = $item->MSN;
           $m->meter_id = Meters::msnmapToid($m->meter_msn);
           $m->sub_div_code = Ogpdetail::msnTosubdiv($item->MSN);
           $m->sub_div_name = Ogpdetail::subDivToName($m->sub_div_code);
           $m->meter_ping_date_time = str_replace('T', ' ', $item->PingDateTime);
            $m->save();
        }
    }
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
```

In above code, there are two if conditions

**isSaved($item->MSN)**

```
 $meter = MeterPing::find()->where(['meter_msn' => $msn])->one();

    if($meter)
        return true;
    return false;
```

From the above function, I am trying to check whether the incoming `MSN` is already saved or not. If it's already present in the table it will not save that particular `MSN` but yes save all the other `MSN` that are not saved previously.

**ogpCreated($item->MSN)**

```
 $meter = Ogpdetail::find()->where(['meter_serial' => $msn])->one();

    if($meter)
        return true;
    return false;
```

From the above function, I am trying to check that the incoming `MSN` is `OGP` created or not. Again it should not save any `MSN` which is not `OGP` created.

Now, when I try to run this `Create` function it only saves one record at a time.

I think there is some issue in `if..... elseif` that only allows saving one entry. But I am not sure of that.

**Update 1**

I have tried to remove the checks and then save the incoming data but still, it only saves one record

How can I save the entire received `JSON` data into my `DB` with all checks working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your model initialization `$m=new YourModel();` inside the `foreach` loop an within the `elseif($this->ogpCreated($item->MSN))`, that is why it is saving only one record

```
foreach ($record as $item){

 if($this->isSaved($item->MSN)){
        return false;
 }
 else if($this->ogpCreated($item->MSN)){
    $m= new YourModel();
```

You are using the `$m` in the curl command too it would be better to post all code incase you run into some logical errors you need to adjust the code accordingly, or change the name of the variable from `$m` inside the `foreach`

Apart from this you can use this extension [**`Yii2-Curl`**](https://github.com/linslin/Yii2-Curl) for curl commands it will allow you more flexibility to your code in a more readable way

Comment: i am talking about this statement `$m->start_date_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');` @MrFaisal

Comment: oh ok i will arrange it :)